# Why is this scope variable not triggering a change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following plunkr: [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lB8MAxhqtFuJN3vegRLi?p=preview). Can anyone please explain why the trimName directive is not changing the text on the template? I see in the console the text "trimming", but I don't see it reflected. I think I am in "angular world" cause I see an `$apply already in progress` if I try to $apply the scope.

Comment: Given what you are doing here is it possible you could just use a "trim" filter: http://jsfiddle.net/tUyyx/

Comment: Ah, no. It was just an example. I'm not really looking for a trim function. I was trying to figure out what the underlying problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can think of the issue as something like "race condition"
The `$digest` is already in progress and your value gets overridden by AngularJS.

Simple workaround will be to evaluate your statement later by using `$evalAsync`:

```
if(scope.trimName.length > intLimit) {
  scope.$evalAsync(function () {
    scope.trimName = scope.trimName.substring(0, intLimit) + "...trimmed";
  });
}
```

[Here is an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/OQp0quXK1bI3JHYbhifj?p=preview).

Comment: This is awesome! I've been banging my head against the wall for almost two hours :D

Comment: I understand your pain...I had similar issue before few weeks... :)